# How to change XYZ coordinate into another 2D system

Tags: c++, math, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I have 3D point set lying on a vertical plane. This plane is not parallel to either X or Y axis but makes an angle (say, θ) to X axis. And also it has some (+ or −) intercept to the X axis.

Now, I want to update my X axis parallel to the azimuthal direction of my plane. And then I want to lie down the vertical plane to XY plane. So, I think I could use my original Z coordinates as the new Y coordinates. As the plane lie on XY plane, there should not be Z coordinates any more. So, I want to know how to get my new X coordinates from the original XYZ and θ.

Actually, I want to implement this modification in c++. But I am really poor in mathematics and struggling to figure out what should be the formula.

After doing this, I want to do some process with the new XY point coordinates. And at the end, I want to bring back all my coordinates to original system. That is finally I want to go back to my original XYZ axes. So I am also looking your assistant to get this case too.

Your assistant is highly appreciated.

Note: So what I did is;
I found the azimuthal angle of the plane and then shift the point data with respect to smallest `X` and `Y` i.e. XY coordinates of the lower left corner of my point set. then, I got new X, Y as (X', Y'):

```
X' = X * cos (θ) + Y * sin(θ) 
Y' = Z
```

Not sure whether my way is correct or not.. I like to learn this.

Comment: cos and sine functions need to be used to solve the problem. Also, its easier and faster to align the plane to the initial coordinate system than to align the coordinate system to the plane. Computer graphics is the subject you need to get yourself familiar with. Transformation matrix may help too..

Comment: Try doing it in two dimensions first. If you can't work it out, show what you've tried.

Comment: @Peter Wood: I updated the post with what I did

Comment: Try it with some numbers. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Peter Wood: i like to learn this. please help me..

Comment: After the first transformation, do you want the point (0,0,0) to be in the plane?

Comment: @Beta: No, Actually, when I computed the X', Y', then I got negative values. So, I subtract lowest left corner coordinates from the whole point. Actually, What I want is to get my X axis along the line given by the XY projected plane. (My plane is vertical plane), Any help please,... I am very poor in this mathematics.

Comment: you can try algebraic [transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of the coordinate system for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't make any sense out of what you said about "the lower left corner of my point set", but if I understand "the azimuthal angle of the plane" correctly, then the first transformation will be this:

```
X' =  X * cos(θ) + Y * sin(θ)
Y' = -X * sin(θ) + Y * cos(θ)
Z' =  Z
```

You should play around with this, make sure you understand it, make sure it's what you want, before you go any farther.

After this transformation, all points in the plane should have the same Y' value.

The second transformation ("lying down") will be this:

```
X" = X'
Y" = Y' + Z'
Z" = 0
```

**You must remember what the Y' value was, in order to reverse this transformation later.**

After you have done whatever you want to do in these coordinates, you can reverse the process to get back to your original coordinate system:

```
X' = X"
Y' = Y'
Z' = Y" - Y'

X = X' * cos(θ) - Y' * sin(θ)
Y = X' * sin(θ) + Y' * cos(θ)
Z = Z'
```

Comment: thank you. now it is clear. actually, I got - values for new xy coordinates so that i shifted the origin. But when I plot a points, then I realised that even though the point lie in first quadrant, after the rotation, those point might have neagative x,y values. thanks for your answer. I learnt a lot. thanks again